# Can a web servers initiate communication with web browsers?

Tags: webserver, browser

I was wondering can web servers **initiate** communication with web browsers? 
from my understanding they communicate but can web server innitiate it?

Answer (score 2):

No. The client must establish and maintain some kind of connection, ie HTTP, WebSocket, or AJAX before the server can send any data. Once the browser window is closed the session is lost and the server can send no more data. In WebSockets the server can push data asynchronously but only through the established connection that the client initiated.

Comment: So this wiki snippet "is made possible by providing a standardized way for the server to send content to the browser without being solicited by the client," ... Is it wrong? Or maybe it assumes a client already initiated a WS connection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the WebSocket technology, takes a  look here:

[WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Answer (score 0):

Web servers using HTTP cannot. However, there are some new web technologies around the corner that hope to change that. 
Check out [SPDY](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper). One of their technical goals is:

> To enable the server to initiate communications with the client and push data to the client whenever possible.